# YAML parse error on curl command parameters

Tags: docker, curl, kubernetes, yaml, markdown

I'm trying to create a small cronjob in k8s that simply executes a HTTP Post using curl in a busybox container. The formatting is wrong though and i cannot figure out what i have to change.

I've tried googling the error message i'm getting as well as change the formatting of the curl command in various ways without any success.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
#namespace: test
metadata:
  name: test-cron
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: test-cron
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - curl "https://test-es01.test.svc.clu01.test.local:9200/logs_write/_rollover" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"conditions: {"max_size": "5gb"}}'
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

I then try to run the file:

`kubectl -n test apply -f test-cron.yaml`

and get the following error:

`error: error parsing test-cron.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 20: mapping values are not allowed in this context`

Does anyone know what the issue is with the formatting?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

thats because your `curl` command contains semicolon so yaml thinks you are trying to define an object. to fix the error:

1. escape every `"` with backlslash:  `\"`
2. wrap the entire line with `"`

therefore-

```
 - curl "https://test-es01.test.svc.clu01.test.local:9200/logs_write/_rollover" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"conditions: {"max_size": "5gb"}}'
```

should be escaped to

```
- "curl \"https://test-es01.test.svc.clu01.test.local:9200/logs_write/_rollover\" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{\"conditions: {\"max_size\": \"5gb\"}}'\n"
```

http://www.yamllint.com/ is a great place to track down such bugs.

Comment: Thank you. Everything now works as expected, except that the busybox image doesn't contain curl... Another problem :)

Comment: is busybox is working with curl command. When I am trying with above yaml file always getting error as curl command not found.

Comment: @Baharul you can either use `wget` instead of `curl`, or use an `alpine` image instead of a `busybox` one, or add the `curl` binary in your dockerfile. https://github.com/docker-library/busybox/issues/47

Comment: In my case I couldn't figure out the correct escaping, but removing the space after the semicolon also made the YAML valid! So `-H 'Content-Type:application/json'` worked.

Comment: The workaround for me was to use the folded block scalar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68269013/705296. For context, this was an issue in a GitHub action workflow, and wrapping in quotes would have resulted in a very long line.