# How to run curl request in yml

Tags: curl, yaml

I have the following curl request which I want to use in my config.yml file for my CircleCI pipeline.

But it keeps giving me errors and I cannot find the right syntax to get it to work.
I put the file in YAML lint and the error is mapping values are not allowed in this context.
Here is my curl request

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":"This is a test!"}' [WEBHOOK URL]
```

Here is my config.yml file:

```
version: 2.1

jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/circleci-python
    docker:
      - image: "circleci/python:3.6.4"
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: python3 main.py
  test:
    working_directory: ~/circleci-python
    docker:
      - image: "circleci/python:3.6.4"
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: python3 main-test.py      
      - run: curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":"This is a test!"}' [WEBHOOK URL]
workflows:
  build_and_test:
    jobs:
      - build
      - test:
          requires:
            - build
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a folded block scalar:

```yaml
version: 2.1

jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/circleci-python
    docker:
      - image: "circleci/python:3.6.4"
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: python3 main.py
  test:
    working_directory: ~/circleci-python
    docker:
      - image: "circleci/python:3.6.4"
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: python3 main-test.py      
      - run: >-
          curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json'
          --data '{"text":"This is a test!"}' [WEBHOOK URL]
workflows:
  build_and_test:
    jobs:
      - build
      - test:
          requires:
            - build
```

`>` starts a folded block scalar. The following `-` tells YAML to strip the final line break which would otherwise be part of the value.

Block scalars do not use quotes or escape sequences and end when their indentation level is left. They are ideal for entering values that use syntax similar to YAML. Folded block scalars fold line breaks into a single space, which allows you to break the command into multiple lines, as I did here.

The reason you get an error is that YAML reads `curl -X POST -H 'Content-type` as an implicit key – think of it like *b* in the line `- a: b: c`. This is not allowed by YAML syntax. The single quote in the curl line does not prevent this since quotation that is inside an unquoted scalar is just parsed as content without any special rules.

Comment: I have container and was intending to run something like this inside the command [] args []. Would your suggestion work there also?

Comment: @Asher Please post a new question. This here is mainly a syntax discussion and your inquiry seems more complex and definitely needs example code to show what you're trying to do.